# How to Add google mob in React Native

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I want to Add GoogleAdMob in My react-native-app(android).
I heard that the expo-admob will bo no longer supported. So I want to use

react-native-google-mobil-ads (https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads)
But Nothing executed and i got this error.

Below is my effort to add google-admob in my react-native-app

---

1. npx create-react-native-app [app_name]
2. add below code in  App.json

```
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

3. add Below code in my App.js

```
import mobileAds from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
import { AppOpenAd, InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

mobileAds()
  .initialize()
  .then(adapterStatuses => {
    // Initialization complete!
  });

<BannerAd unitId={TestIds.BANNER} />
```

But I got the error

```
export { AdEventType } from './AdEventType';
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./AdEventType from
File Directory\node_modules\react-native-google-mobile-ads\src\index.ts:

  28 | export { MaxAdContentRating } from './MaxAdContentRating';        
  29 | export { TestIds } from './TestIds';
> 30 | export { AdEventType } from './AdEventType';
     |                              ^
  31 | export { BannerAdSize } from './BannerAdSize';
  32 | export { GAMAdEventType } from './GAMAdEventType';
  33 | export { RewardedAdEventType } from './RewardedAdEventType';      
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at async addDependency (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async processModule (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:279:3)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dance_Platform\banner-second\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:221:3) 
    at async traverseDependencies (File_Directory\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:147:7)
```

---

Anything I should do additional to add google-mob ?